# Resetting variables when loading a cached page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which sets the a value of a js variable for customer authentication to false inside 
"jQuery(document).ready(function()" when it is loaded for the first time.

but after customer authenticates himself and then comes back to that same page, that page is loaded from cache and the value still remains as it is

So is there a way by which i can force that variable to reset itself ??

Comment: you could use cookie instead of a js variable

Comment: Are you redirecting the user to that page after authentication? Redirection should not refill the data from cache.

Comment: I have a link on d page which redirects to home page when authenticated or opens a login page dialog when unauthenticated

Answer (score 1):

can check when the page becomes visible using-

```
$('#mypage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
          //Reset the vars here.. 
        });
```

OR

shorter way is

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    //event.persisted)
    //Reset the vars here.. 

};
```